# How to enable TLSv1.1 with Java7

Tags: ssl, soap, salesforce, java-7

One of the third party applications(salesforce) that my application is communicating is moving to TLSv1.1 protocol and closing TLSv1.0. So we are migrating our application from Java6 to Java7 (for some reasons we cannot migrate to java8). However, TLSv1.1 is not enabled by default in Java7. After checking on internet, we got to know that we can enable TLSv1.1 by setting parameter

-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.1"

Setting this parameter is not working for us. I have set this parameter in my Jboss server's wrapper.conf file.

Is there any setting needed in Java security or elsewhere to enable TLSv1.1 ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Java SE 7 release supports TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2, neither version is enable by default for client connections    
You could try adding something like the following to your startup script, assuming Java 1.7:

JAVACMD="$JAVACMD -Ddeployment.security.SSLv2Hello=false -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false -D\
deployment.security.TLSv1.1=true -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true"
```

For Java 7 on Windows, you go to System Preferences > Java, and the Java Control Panel opens in a separate window. Then you go to the Advanced tab and scroll down to the Advanced Security Settings section and check the Use TLS 1.1 and Use TLS 1.2 checkboxes.